# Is there some useful, money making activity for people who have a lot of free time, on the job, intermittently, like some cab drivers?

Tags: work-time, freelancing, employment, part-time, self-employment

Guess - the solution might be using internet connected smartphones in some way (*as they are relatively widespread and connectivity is improving*), utilizing the human mind to overcome limitations of computing. It should require minimal training.

Edit - Not asking for myself in particular, assume that the worker is allowed to do the task in between the main job

(reworded)

Comment: Professional CAPTCHA solver companies do this to an extent but that is probably illegal and short lived. Another idea I had - live surveillance of public CCTV camera footage, via a distributed feed, paying members to keep an eye, with suitable reward for reporting irregularities?

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking. Are you trying to find a way to occupy yourself when you don't have anything to do on the job?

Comment: Do you have skills for proof reading and stuff like that?  If you have document review skills then doing that while waiting could be a huge thing.  Not sure that you can get in that door though without some skill sets and training to prove it.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, e.g. a taxi driver, waiting for a customer for say, 30 minutes, can she do something that can generate a small income ?

Comment: @mutt I'm not asking for myself in particular. But I'm getting your idea. I feel the task should have small easily doable chunks, which can be completed in gaps between regular work

Comment: @DSR yes, the main thing to be sure is the cab company doesn't have any rules in their employees getting pay while on the job.  It seems unlikely in this particular case, but in software and other places it's illegal to utilize company assets or time for additional pay.  I'd check on any rules like that for the company.

Comment: Why does the question have -2 votes ? Can someone help on the reasons/remediation ?

Comment: Your question got a negative reception and was closed because it's not really a good fit for the site and it's still unclear what type of answer you're looking for. Asking for job or product recommendations is off-topic here. Check the [help/on-topic] and [tour] to learn more. Note that closing questions is typically a community matter and you'll want to raise the issue on [meta] or [chat] instead of flagging your question for a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome).  It's a marketplace where people perform short tasks (like describing images, transcribing audio, etc.) in exchange for money.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much anything that can be stopped/started at a moments notice. Studying for certifications is always worthwhile although you don't get immediate return. I knew a guy who knitted Rastafarian hats and had a steady source of income out of it. All you need is a product and a market.

I think making and selling something you own is best.

Comment: Knitting Rastafarian hats is what I was thinking too :)

Comment: His relative owned some sort of shop, he could make $100 extra on a slow day. It was good money.

Comment: Nice idea, but does require substantial skills

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things you can do, but I doubt any of them will really provide a lot of income. I've signed up for survey companies before, and now I get flooded with emails asking me to take surveys for fractions of pennies. A lot of those you can finish in 10 to 20 minutes.